# Load input file convert to custom array objects in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a situation where I want to load a custom-based file to memory and pass it as array to AWS resource.

Here is my file (this is ***not*** JSON)

abc.tmpl

```
{
 name="Mark"
 age="20"
},
{
 name="Steve"
 age="25"
}
```

apply the above values to one of the resources in the array below

```
module "elb" {
 custome_elb_settings = [
  {
   name="Mark"
   age="20"
  },
  {
   name="Steve"
   age="25"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I tried with template_file it loaded in plain text and loaded as 1 string with \n and escape chars in it.

Is there any way to load as objects from file or else convert string to array in Terraform

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a variable:

```
variable "custome_elb_settings" {
  type = list(object({name=string,age=number}))
}

module "elb" {
  custome_elb_settings = var.custome_elb_settings
}
```

Then pass the value in the command line:

```
terraform apply -var custome_elb_settings="[ $(cat abc.tmpl) ]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see it is accepting it, but not taking as type list. We have common module and it accepts list type.

Comment: Yes, you need to declare the variable to be of proper type. I updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks again for all your valuable input.